# Pygame image not showing up / blitting

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game with pygame, and it's my first time. I am having trouble with how to 'blit' images, and when I try nothing appears on the window.

I've already caught a few problems, and made sure that I update the display and 'blitted' the image with coodrinates.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

# py-game variables
(width, height) = (1000, 600)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
window_title = pygame.display.set_caption('the CATANALYSER')
does_quit = False

# py-game images
hexagon_image = pygame.image.load('hexagon image.png')


# py-game window loop
while not does_quit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            does_quit = True

    window.blit(hexagon_image, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

the expected result is a screen with the image hexagon_image in the uppermost left hand corner.

No error messages show up with this code.

Comment: Its working fine for me. You might want to wait for some time so that the window gets initialized

Comment: Also, make sure the window isn't appearing somewhere in the background.